# nginx location rewrite not matching

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

In our nginx configuration we have defined the following rewrite to forward requests to another domain:

```
location /service {
  rewrite ^/service/(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/service/$1 redirect;
}
```

It matches URLs like `http://www.example.com/service/test123` but the following URL does not match:

```
https://www.example.com/service/imprint/acc/123456/ext_css/http://www3.example.com/formulare/css/service.css
```

Yes there is a second URL after /ext_css/ and we now that's not correct but at the moment there is no way to change that.

Is there a way to completely forward the whole path to the new server?

```
/service/imprint/acc/123456/ext_css/http://www3.example.com/formulare/css/service.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it outside of the location block did the trick.

Instead of

```
location /service {
  rewrite ^/service/(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/service/$1 redirect;
}
```

we now have just

```
rewrite ^/service/(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/service/$1 redirect;
```

Now it matches everything written after `/service/`